# JQuery .attr won't retrieve or change values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change HTML attributes using jQuery, but no matter what I do, I can't get anything to work with jQuery's .attr().

For testing, I've written

```
alert($("#logo").attr("title"));
```

and even though I have an img with id="logo" and a title, the alert remains blank.

My full method:

```
function switchVideo(videoID) {
    var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
    videoPlayer.src = "video/Occam.webm";
    videoPlayer.load();
    $("#example_video_1").attr("poster", "video/ss.png");

    //Doesn't work:
    alert($("#logo").attr("title"));
    $("#logo").fadeOut();

    videoPlayer.play();
}
```

My fade out works, so I know I imported jQuery correctly.

I've gotten it working in another document, so there must be something else in the document messing it up. Does anyone know why this simple method won't work?

You can see the source page at http://jrstrauss.net/temp/create.html

Comment: when is this function called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your div has the id logo, not the img. 
Try:

`$("#logo img").attr("title")`

Comment: yeah, it made me wait a certain amount of time before i could

Answer (score 3):

You should be using $.fn.prop for that now: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Are you sure about that? (It doesn't actually make any difference to the result anyway though - http://jsfiddle.net/YRg2W/)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `prop` if you are using a recent version of jQuery.

Comment: `prop` should be used for boolean elements like `checked`, but I can't find anything in the JQuery documentation that says it is deprecated for normal properties like `title`.

Comment: @Daniel Are you sure about that? (It doesn't actually make any difference to the result anyway though - http://jsfiddle.net/YRg2W/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this according to your HTML:

```
alert( $("#logo a img").attr("title") );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VcLNq/)

Answer (score 1):

You have the following markup with id `logo`

```
<div id="logo">
......
</div>
```

Now, you are trying to run jQuery's `.attr` method by following code.

```
$("#logo").attr("title");
```

as you may know `.attr` method retrieves attribute value of the given element but that `<div>` doesn't have a attribute named title. so to confirm this, try retrieving attribute that does exist, for example `id`. so try this

```
alert($("#logo").attr("id"));
```

This will return the value of attribute. the important thing to note is jQuery looks for attributes of given element only, It doesn't scan child elements.

So, to make it work in your case. You need to do the following

```
alert($("#logo img").attr("title"));
```

Hope it helps